# Add Date to ASP .NET Core 2.1 default logger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

I'm using ASP.NET's default logger which is creating logs like that

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data, this mode should only be enabled during development.
```

But I'd want to attach DateTime.Now to it like

```
[2019.12.19 10:00] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[2019.12.19 10:00] warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data, this mode should only be enabled during development.
```

I tried using Serilog but I couldnt get those default logs, only those that I directly created 
 `Log.Error("error");` were shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the discussed issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/483) on github ,the built-in .NET Core console logger doesn't log date-time.

You could try [a custom console logger](https://github.com/ilya-chumakov/LoggingAdvanced) to automatically log the timestamp

1.Customize LoggerBuilderExtensions with AddConsoleAdvanced method

```
public static class LoggerBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Adds a console logger named 'ConsoleAdvanced' to the factory.</summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder" /> to use.</param>
    /// <param name="loggingSection"></param>
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddConsoleAdvanced(this ILoggingBuilder builder,
        IConfiguration loggingSection)
    {
        if (loggingSection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggingSection));

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider,
                AdvancedConsoleLoggerProvider>());

        //We can't read the result of logging.AddConfiguration mtd here, cause it registers internal classes (without public interfaces).
        //So, a configuration section must be passed to configure the logger.
        builder.Services.TryAdd(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConsoleLoggerSettings>(
                provider => new ConfigurationConsoleLoggerSettings(loggingSection)));

        return builder;
    }

    /// <summary>Adds a console logger named 'ConsoleAdvanced' to the factory.</summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder" /> to use.</param>
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddConsoleAdvanced(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, AdvancedConsoleLoggerProvider>());

        builder.Services.TryAdd(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConsoleLoggerSettings>(provider =>ConsoleLoggerSettings.Optimized));

        return builder;
    }

    /// <summary>Adds a console logger named 'ConsoleAdvanced' to the factory.</summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder" /> to use.</param>
    /// <param name="settings">The formatting settings, timezone, etc.</param>
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddConsoleAdvanced(this ILoggingBuilder builder,
        IConsoleLoggerSettings settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, AdvancedConsoleLoggerProvider>());

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(provider => settings));

        return builder;
    }
}
```

2.customize the logger

```
     public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsoleAdvanced(new ConsoleLoggerSettings()
                {
                    IncludeLineBreak = false,
                    IncludeTimestamp = true,
                    IncludeZeroEventId = false,
                    IncludeLogNamespace = false
                });

            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.Net Core, you can configure the logger to include timestamps.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logger=>
            {
                logger.AddConsole(x => x.TimestampFormat = "[HH:mm:ss] "); 
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseIIS();
            });
    }
```

Comment: I have .NET Core 2.1 and as far as I see this exist in newer versions :(